# If two functions are undefined at the same points, are they "equal for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$"?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, terminology

Consider two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. $f(x)$ is only equal to $g(x)$ in terms of expression, when their domains are ignored.

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both undefined for, let's say $x = \pi$, are they equal for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$? At point $x = \pi$ they both become undefined at the same time, yet is it correct to say that they are "equal" in $\mathbb{R}$?

One example is $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \tan x$. At $x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2} \dots$, both $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $\tan x$ are undefined, at the same time. Yet, is it correct to say that they are "equal for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: *"equal for any* $x \in \mathbb{R}$" -- Since this could be misleading, I would not say that in this case, whether or not someone can successfully argue that it is technically correct (BTW, I don't think it is technically correct), but instead I would say something like "equal for any $x$ in their common domain". Somewhat relevant: [What is common domain of two equal function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3176755/13130)

Comment: Not really. It's better to say "they agree on their domains, which are the same".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - I considered "common domain" too, but was worried that some may take that to refer to the intersections of their domains, which may not be equal. That may not be the convention, but that's why I offered my more verbose version.

Comment: @JonathanZ: I somewhat wondered about this myself as I was writing my comment. Then your first comment popped up (less than 2 seconds after I pressed "Add comment" for my comment), and your first comment got me to wonder a bit more, and of course your second comment . . . I definitely see your point. I can think of several ways to be more exact, but I think this is one of those things I'd have to know something about the intended reader before deciding on how to phrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say the answer is a *it depends* in the sense that if you have some input domain $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ and two functions
$$
f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
$$
g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
such that for all $x\in A$ $f(x)=g(x)$ then $f,g$ are the same function on that domain. When you say equal "for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$", you need to be specific about what you mean because our functions are not defined in that way and need to then be extended into the domain in some way.

For example we can say that at every undefined point $a$ that
$$
f(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)
$$
for which in this case $f,g$ would still be equal. However if we just said "let $f$ be $0$ on undefined points and let $g$ be $1$ on undefined points in our extension" then they would not be the same.

That second version is outside the norm though and in everyday speak we would just say the functions are the same.

By the way, $\tan(x)$ is defined to be $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ so they would be equiv by definition